# AttributeError: SyncToDisk?

Tags: python, osgeo

I want to save my 'feat' - selected by criteria polygons in shp.file to save   in diferent shp.file on the disk     by using SyncToDisk() in osgeo      for vector.
Code gives me error:  AttributeError: SyncToDisk.

What can be wrong?

```
import osgeo, os
from osgeo import ogr, gdal

shpFile = r'C:\Users\ReBurns.shp'

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

ptsDS = driver.Open(shpFile)
ptsLayer = ptsDS.GetLayer()

#Passing criteria  to select polygons:    
myQuery = 'Area_ha > 39000.00'
ptsLayer.SetAttributeFilter(myQuery)
print ptsLayer
ptsLayer.GetFeatureCount()

for i in range(0, ptsLayer.GetFeatureCount()):
    pt = ptsLayer.GetNextFeature()
    print pt.GetField('Area_ha')

for i in range( 0, ptsLayer.GetFeatureCount()):
    feat = ptsLayer.GetFeature( i )
    print feat
feat.SyncToDisk(r'C:\Users\ReBurns_Diss_Alb111.shp')
feat = None
```

Comment: It is saying that there is no method called SyncToDisk on the object you are calling. I don't get what you are trying to do, so perhaps you need some more explanation. I think you probably want to sync a data source, not the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SyncToDisk`](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Layer-class.html#SyncToDisk) is a method of a `Layer` object, not a feature.  It doesn't take any parameters and is not used to save the layer to a new dataset on disk (which I presume you are trying to do).  From a quick scan of the [documentation](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Layer-class.html#SyncToDisk), it appears to be used when you are editing/updating a layer and want to commit those changes:

> SyncToDisk
>
> Flush pending changes to disk.
>
> This call is intended to force the layer to flush any pending writes
>   to disk, and leave the disk file in a consistent state.

To copy your layer with the attribute filter applied, you could do something like:

```
outds = driver.CreateDataSource(r'C:\Users\ReBurns_Diss_Alb111.shp')
outlyr = outds.CopyLayer(ptsLayer,'ReBurns_Diss_Alb111')
```

Note that this code

```
for i in range( 0, ptsLayer.GetFeatureCount()):
    etc...
```

can (and probably will) produce unexpected results, especially with a filter applied, as the `GetFeature` method does not get features by index, but by FID (feature ID). And to make things worse... I think it will ignore any filters...

To loop over the features in the filtered layer, just use:

```
for feat in ptsLayer:
    etc...
```

Comment: Thank you, but there are No any features in the file 'ReBurns_Diss_Alb111'? When I use outds = driver.CreateDataSource(r'C:\Users\ReBurns_Diss_Alb111.shp')
outlyr = outds.CopyLayer(ptsLayer,'ReBurns_Diss_Alb111')
 What can be a problem?  .

Comment: @Adams post a new question